# Spring Ouath2 Registered Redirect Uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring OAuth2 to enable login with SoundCloud. I've have already registered my *callback url*. So when I am using Spring OAuth2 and set my redirect url explicitly it forced me to process it manually (by providing some controller for it).

I put it in *application.yml* :

```
pre-established-redirect-uri: https://localhost:8443/callback
use-current-uri: false
```

and i got 404 with :

```
https://localhost:8443/callback?code=...
```

Can I force Spring OAuth2 get access token automatically without handling callback?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to handle the callback to get the access token from sound cloud Api.
Spring-social is helpful to get the access token without handling callback but that is available only for Facebook,  Twitter and LinkedIn for now. You can check this link about spring social :

http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/core.html

Just checked it looks like someone has tried to provide the sound cloud api binding with spring-social. But I doubt it's completeness.
You can check this link to get an idea :

https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-social-soundcloud

Comment: i use spring oauth2 exactly cause it fits any oauth2 service (facebook, linkedin, github), but spring-social is limited. i just want to figure out how spring oauth2 manage callbacks. i used it many times for service where i can reconfigure my callback url